# How long does it take for fluid to clear from the lungs on average and how does this happen?

Tags: breathing, choking

If a person somehow gets a fixed amount of fluid or fine particles into their lungs such as by accidentally inhaling rather than swallowing and the cough reflex doesn't expel it how is it removed and how long does this take on average?

I have so far searched for 'what happens when you inhale liquid' which generally says that if any reaches the vocal chords the cough reflect will expel it, but inevitably this could be suppressed or might not be enough to expel all liquids and fine particles so I am curious about that aspect in particular. People with minor pulmonary edemas don't always have liquid removed from their lungs through surgery right? So how is it removed if at all?